# How to get days date based on their short name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an API in my web service which return days in which a shop is available to delivery, the API returns an object with id (which is needed then to get hours based on selected day) and day short name (in italian).

Before the API i was using the following function which was generating an array of days, and to today i was adding 'Today' tag.

```
  times(giorniMax: number, giorni: NegozioGiorni[]): void {
    const options = { weekday: 'short', day: 'numeric', month: 'short' };
    const today = new Date();
    this.giorni.push({ // adding today to days array
      formatted: 'Oggi, ' + today.toLocaleString('it-IT', options),
      time: today.toLocaleDateString(),
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < giorniMax; i++) { // adding all other days based on max days per week variable 'giorniMax'
      today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
      this.giorni.push({
        formatted: today.toLocaleDateString('it-IT', options),
        time: today.toLocaleDateString(),
      });
    }
  }
```

But as now i have the API which return the available days of week in `giorni.giorno` i was wondering on how i can generate the same kind of days array but based on available days from array `giorni`..

Here is how `NegozioGiorni[]` looks like:

```
[{id: 1, giorno: "TUE"}, {id: 2, giorno: "WED"}, {id: 3, giorno: "THU"}, {id: 4, giorno: "FRI"}]
```

And based on that array from function times() i should get an array like this:

```
Today, Wed 23 Sep - Thu 24 Sep - Fri 25 Sep - Tue 29 Sep
```

Or if Today does not exist just show the next days in the array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library with it's `.isoWeekday` function in the following way:

```
    moment.locale('it'); // setting locale to italian as API response returns it formatted days

    const days = ['lun', 'mar', 'mer', 'gio', 'ven', 'sab', 'dom']; // mapping weekdays which will be used to get index of the day to use in isoWeekday

    const momentToday = moment().isoWeekday(); // setting today date
    const arrayGiorni = giorni.map((g) => {
      const dayIndex = days.indexOf(g.giorno.toLowerCase()); // getting index of day from the object array es if g.giorno is 'mar' index will be 2
      if (momentToday <= dayIndex) { // checking if today is <= to mapping object then adding it to array
        return {
          id: g.id,
          giorno: moment().isoWeekday(dayIndex),
        };
      } else { // else skipping to next week and adding the object to array
        return {
          id: g.id,
          giorno: moment()
            .add(1, 'weeks')
            .isoWeekday(dayIndex),
        };
      }
    });

// sorting the array to get an ordered array of dates
    arrayGiorni.sort((a, b) => moment(a.giorno).valueOf() - moment(b.giorno).valueOf());

// formatting the moment object to get string formatted date
    this.giorni = arrayGiorni.map(g => g.giorno.format('ddd DD MMM'));

    console.log(this.giorni);
```

All suggestions on how to improve the performance of the code above are welcome.